# what is the wso2 api manager plan in future and when the wso2am 1.7.0 come out?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

where to know the wso2 api manger plan in future?
what is the future direction?
and who know when the wso2am 1.7 come out?

And I want to know wso2 about the api manager future development?

Answer (score 0):

You could refer [WSO2 API Manager JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER/) for rough dates for API Manager release plans.

If you wanted to use WSO2 API Manager for your solution please use "[Contact US](http://wso2.com/contact/)" form on WSO2 site or if you wanted to contribute the project drop a mail to dev@wso2.org mentioning your idea.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 AM 1.7.0 is already released. You can download it from [1].

[1] - http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/